# Set Types for HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob callback and URL.createObjectURL

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I am using React with Typescript to handle images. I found [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/y09komm059?file=/src/canvasUtils.js:0-3326) great CodeSandbox from react-easy-crop, where they have a utils file using the following snippet:

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
    canvas.toBlob((file) => {
        resolve(URL.createObjectURL(file));
    }, 'image/png');
});
```

This snipped throws the following Typecsript error complaining about the file parameter passed to `URL.createObjectURL(file)`: Argument of type 'Blob | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Blob | MediaSource'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Blob | MediaSource'.ts(2345)

As URL.createObjectURL() is expecting a type like Blob | MediaSource, I tried to give this type to the callback function parameter like this:

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
    canvas.toBlob((file: Blob | MediaSource) => {
        resolve(URL.createObjectURL(file));
    }, 'image/png');
});
```

But this throws a new Typescript error: Argument of type '(file: Blob | MediaSource) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BlobCallback'.
Types of parameters 'file' and 'blob' are incompatible.
Type 'Blob | null' is not assignable to type 'Blob | MediaSource'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Blob | MediaSource'.ts(2345)

Can anyone please advise about how to handle the types for the file parameter? thank you.

Comment: I use the same library and had the same problem. Any chance you could possibly create a pull request for the project to add your TypeScript working example? It would be a great help for the community and save everyone a lot of time! Of course this is just a suggestion, but I think it will be very useful :)

Comment: Hi @R.Boutte, happy to do it, but I think that the issue is not in the core of the crop library, but in one of the demo files: docs/src/components/Demo/cropImage.ts is that the file you are getting the error from? 
That file was adapted from this other file: test/imgPreview.ts from this other cropping library: https://github.com/DominicTobias/react-image-crop where the case for null is handled with the if.
I am happy to help if you are having issues with the demo file from the react-easy-crop library. Just need to pin-point where the issue would be addressed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your motivation! Here is [the current file](https://codesandbox.io/s/y09komm059?file=/src/canvasUtils.js:3228-3258) I was converting to TypeScript. I think we maybe should create another example but using TS for the same features. Which demo are you basing your code? Is it already in TS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is complaining that `file` can be null, which would not be a good thing to pass in `URL.createObjectURL`.

If you know that it can never be null, use an assertion:

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
    canvas.toBlob((file) => {
        resolve(URL.createObjectURL(file!));
//                                      ^ '!' used as assertion
    }, 'image/png');
});
```

Otherwise, handle it appropriately first with an if statement.